# How to create a new ndarray after performing a calculation on a slice

Tags: python, slice, numpy-ndarray, inequalities

I have a 4d numpy array, I want to perform a calculation on several slices of it and then create a new array with all the values in. The main problem is I have fixed slices for 3 dimensions but then several ranges for the fourth axis how do I slice by ranges on the 4th axis please

Comment: Can you give some examples of the shapes of your composite array, your slices and the result array you want?

Comment: `x[:, :, :, start:end]`?

Comment: This I know how to do but I want where the 4th axis is entries10-20 35-45 and 60-70,thanks in advance!

Comment: Having that in the question, ideally as part of a [mcve], would be a huge improvement.

Answer (score 1):

While I think there are several similar questions on here already (38 results for `numpy 4d slice`), here's my attempt to visually explain this.
First, I downloaded a `.gif` from Giphy and converted it into an exemplary multidimensional `np.array()`; it is 200x200px in size, has 3 colour channels, 6 frames, resulting in a shape of `(6, 200, 200, 3)`.

[image]

In the first row of the plot, I show each color channel separately, and the total sum of the frame with index `1` (note that the `cmap` keyword is disregarded here).

Next, I create a specific slice of the green channel (color index `1`), which goes from 50-150px in y-direction, and 100-120px in x-direction like so: `my_slice= frames[frame_index,50:150,100:120,1]` — it has shape `(100, 20)`. 
I multiply it by 0.1, and insert the result in the original position.

The second image row now shows how I reduced the green channel in this region, yielding to an overall pink hue in the total image.

If you now would like to perform this action on e.g. frames `[0,4,5]`, it becomes a simple `for frame_index in [0,4,5]:` loop.
Hope this helps.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image, ImageSequence

## downloaded from here: 
# https://media.giphy.com/media/uQCxA7u9CEdIA/200w_d.gif
img = Image.open("/path/to/Downloads/brainscan.gif")
frames = np.array([np.array(frame.copy().convert('RGB').getdata(),dtype=np.uint8).reshape(frame.size[1],frame.size[0],3) for frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(img)])

print(np.shape(frames))

frame_index=1

fig,axes=plt.subplots(2,4,figsize=(10,4))
axes[0,0].imshow(frames[frame_index,:,:,0],cmap="Reds_r")
axes[0,1].imshow(frames[frame_index,:,:,1],cmap="Greens_r")
axes[0,2].imshow(frames[frame_index,:,:,2],cmap="Blues_r")
axes[0,3].imshow(frames[frame_index,:,:,:],cmap="viridis")

my_slice= frames[frame_index,50:150,100:120,1]
print(np.shape(my_slice[:]))
frames[frame_index,50:150,100:120,1]=0.1*my_slice

axes[1,0].imshow(frames[frame_index,:,:,0],cmap="Reds_r")
axes[1,1].imshow(frames[frame_index,:,:,1],cmap="Greens_r")
axes[1,2].imshow(frames[frame_index,:,:,2],cmap="Blues_r")
axes[1,3].imshow(frames[frame_index,:,:,:],cmap="viridis")


plt.show()
```